# ansible: how to access ansible_env when gather_facts: false

Tags: ansible

I would like to have a minimal fact gathering that would only. I'm actually only interested in accessing the variables defined in ansible_env.

I've tried to use the setup module with filter: ansible_env and gather_subset: min but It didn't work for me...

any hint would be greatly appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I report below a minimal  example:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - setup:
        filter: ansible_env
    - debug:
        var=ansible_env
```

Comment: This will execute full-featured fact gathering by `setup` module and then drop everything except `ansible_env` from results. What is the advantage to `gather_facts: yes`?

Comment: Thanks NoNoNo!

@Konstantin:
I found a side effect of gather_facts: false and it is that environment variables 

If define in a playbook are not automatically exposed as 

`ansible_env.MY_ENV_VAR`

I was hopping that it would be faster than gather_facts: true

Comment: `I was hopping that it would be faster than gather_facts: true` – there will be no speed gain, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of creating a playbook just for that, you can execute an Ansible command like the following, in order to retrieve specific facts:

> ```
> ansible <hostname> -m setup -a "filter=ansible_distribution"
> ```

[Source](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#local-facts-facts-d)

Comment: For some more useful examples of `setup` module usage, execute `ansible-doc setup` from your local system's command prompt.